# creating div id concating variable and string

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

one simple question. How can I create div id value using variable value.

```
<div id="@myVar.Code"+"collapsible"> Click me </div>
```

I tried with above example and rendered html is

```
<div id="9987"+"collapsible">Click me</div>
```

I need this `<div id="9987collapsible">Click me</div>`

Comment: `<div id="@myVar.Codecollapsible"> Click me </div>`

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="@(myVar.Code)collapsible"> Click me </div>
```